# convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does anybody know how to show analytically the convergence (divergence ?) of $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}\enspace$ or some literature for it ? (Thanks!)

*Note*: Unfortunately I am still missing a useful approach.

EDIT:

I want to thank all here for the nice help.

Result: The series is divergent (but limited) as it is written.

It's possible to change to $\enspace\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (-2+\sum\limits_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}})\enspace$ to avoid the oscillation and to get convergence.

Comment: Does it converge? I think it doesn't.

Comment: @EUNSUNGLIM LIM : I think so by numerically tests  ... but maybe my possibilites are not good enough.

Comment: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt{n}]}}{\sqrt n} $= $-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} -\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 4}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 7}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 8} +........ $ . This is an alternating series and hence it is convegent. Because each successive term is numerically less than the preceding term  and $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \rightarrow 0 $

Comment: @mabmath : Thanks, yes (by Leibniz if the terms go to 0) but *each successive term is numerically less than the preceding term* still has to be proofed (I mean: I still have to proof this).

Comment: @mabmath, this is **not** an alternating series.  The signs in an alternating series must go back and forth at *each* step.  (That's what "alternating" means.). You are possibly thinking of Dirichlet's test.  But even there, the running sum of the signs must stay **bounded**, which is not the case here.  As several answers show, the OP's sum diverges.

Comment: @mabmath : I changed to $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n(\sum\limits_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-2)$ and hope this is a Leibniz series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prove that it diverges by observing that the sum of each "block" is greater than a constant, that is, $$\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>C$$for some positive $C$.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this is an alternating set of estimates, upper and lower sub-values ​​are still too inaccurate here - perhaps there are appropriate estimates. I will try.

Comment: The LHS is greater than $(2n+1$) times the smallest term in the sum. So the LHS is greater than $(2n+1)/\sqrt {n^2+2n}\;$ which is greater than $(2n+1)/(n+1)$ which $\to 2$ as $n\to \infty$.................+1.

Comment: To the OP; Why do you say the estimate is too inaccurate? The fact that  the same $C>0$ exists for all $n$ is enough too guarantee divergence.

Comment: This is right. such C exists

Comment: @user254665 : $s_n:=\sum\limits_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ ; If it's $s_n>s_{n+1}$ then the convergence is clear because of Leibniz. But I still haven't proofed this.

Comment: Doesn't Leibniz test require that $s_n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ goes infinity, which I showed to be false?

Comment: @ didgogns : Thanks. If $s_n\to 0$ isn't true than Leibniz doesn't work. I have to check this.

Comment: This answer is correct. My answer goes into more detail and comes to the same conclusion.

Comment: @didgogns : Divergence yes, as it is written. Thank you! But I think the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (s_n-2)$ is convergent, I have to check it.

Comment: To the OP. The fact that  C>0 means the series does not meet the Cauchy criterion for convergence, which is an "iff" criterion.

Comment: More precisely we have $\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=H_{(n+1)^2-1}^{({\frac{1}{2}})}-H_{n^2-1}^{({\frac{1}{2}})}\\= 2 + \frac{1}{2n} +O(\frac{1}{n^3}) $.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I have forgotten how to type in LateX, so here it is by hand.

Basically, this is an explicit version of the other answer.

Essentially, we show that each block has a minimal magnitude (infimum) by which it add or subtracts from the partial sum. This non-decreasing (constant) bound makes the series fail the criteria for the alternating series test (I believe)

[image]

[image]

Interestingly, if we study the blocks of partial terms, they tend towards "$2$" in magnitude, so the series diverges more "hectically" as we take $n$ to infinity than our bound may suggest.

Comment: Thanks! But because of technical reasons I cannot see images at the moment.

Comment: Letting the "epsilons" go to $0$ represents an "even if" scenario. Indeed the sequence of epsilons on the second page, I believe, actually tends to $2-(2/3^{0.5})$

Comment: I would use (absolute value of partial sum)$\ge (2n+1)/(n+1)>1$, it is much simpler. By the way, one can prove that every partial sum is greater than $2$ using simple integral.

Comment: @didgogns : Thanks for the hint, than I have a problem with these partial sums. Do you know what the limit is for the partial sum ($s_n$) for $n\to\infty$ ? Then maybe it's possible to create a Leibniz series by substracting this limit from each $s_n$ .

Comment: @user90369 Sorry about that. I would type it up if I knew how to. Also, didgogns Your idea is better (to simplify it a bit more to begin with). You mean you look at Ln((f(x)) as a bound and factor out (subtract) something large enough?

Comment: Right. Each block is about 2, so the sum oscillates.

Comment: @didgogns :I see, it's 2. :-) So it's possible to write $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (\sum\limits_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-2)$ and check if this is a Leibniz series.

Comment: @Just_a_fool : I will see the images later (I have to change the computer :-)) . Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 1):

This does not converge;
it oscillates by
approximately $2$.

If
$m^2 \le m
\le m^2+2n
$,
then
$\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor
= m$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
S(M)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{M^2+2M} \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{M}
\sum_{n=m^2}^{m^2+2m} \frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{n}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{M}
(-1)^m\sum_{n=m^2}^{m^2+2m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{M}
(-1)^ms(m)
\qquad\text{where }s(m)=\sum_{n=m^2}^{m^2+2m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\
\end{array}
$

$s(m)
\lt \frac{2m+1}{m}
= 2+\frac1{m}
$
and
$s(m)
\gt \frac{2m+1}{m+1}
=2-\frac1{m+1}
$.

Therefore,
as $n$ goes from
$m^2$ to
$m^2+2n$,
the value of the sum
changes by approximately $2$,
increasing when $n$ is even
and
decreasing when $n$ is odd.

Therefore the series does not converge,
since it oscillates.

However,
there might be a sense
in which the series converges
since we can write
$S(2M)
=\sum_{m=1}^{2M}(-1)^ms(m)
=\sum_{m=1}^{M}(s(2m)-s(2m-1))
$.

I can show that that
$s(m)-s(m+1)
\to 0$,
but I can not yet show that
$\lim_{M \to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^{M}(s(2m)-s(2m-1))
$
exists.

Here's what I have so far,
and I will leave it at this:

$\begin{array}\\
s(m)-s(m+1)
&\gt (2-\frac1{m+1})-(2+\frac1{m+1})\\
&= -\frac{2}{m+1}\\
\text{and}\\
s(m)-s(m+1)
&\lt (2+\frac1{m})-(2-\frac1{m+2})\\
&= \frac1{m}+\frac1{m+2}\\
&= \frac{2m+2}{m(m+2)}\\
\text{so}\\
s(m)-s(m-1)
&= O(\frac1{m})\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, it makes sense to write $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (\sum\limits_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}-2)$ and check if this is a Leibniz series.

Comment: Yes. Good idea. The Euler-Maclaurin sum formula would probably be useful.

Answer (score -4):

It's alternating series (with periodically strange alternation, but alternation nonetheless) and thus converges according to alternating series test.

Comment: There are plenty of series with alternating signs which diverge. Take a modified harmonic series such that every 10th term is a negative addend. This series still diverges.

Comment: yes it converges

Comment: @mabmath. Could you elaborate, please ?

Comment: To use alternating series test, we need more conditions but I think that series does not satisfy them

Comment: yes it is , $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt{n}]}}{\sqrt n} $= $-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} -\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 4}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 7}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 8} -\frac{1}{\sqrt 9}-... ........ $ . This is an alternating series and hence it is convegent. Because each successive term is numerically less than the preceding term  and $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \rightarrow 0 $

Comment: @mabmath Alternating means changing sign in each term, which is not the case here.