# Does $\sum\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor}}{ n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $\sum\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor}}{n}$ converge ?

I know there is a technical method that uses an adapted Abel's rule 
$(*)$ ; I would like to know if you see another method (which is understable with basic knowledge) to prove it converges. Thank you.

Remark: Actually, it can be proved that for all $z \in \mathbb C$ such that $|z| = 1$, $\sum\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor}}{ n}z^n$ converges.

$(*)$ Consider two series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$. Define $B_m = \sum_{n=0}^mb_n$

If the sequence $(a_n)$ tends to $0$ and the sequence $(B_n)$ is bonded, and if the series $\sum (a_{n+1} - a_n)$ converges absolutely, then $\sum a_nb_n$ converges.

You have to adapt this theorem to use it here.

Comment: By Abel's rule I am refering to the integration by part applied to series.

Comment: This may be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222371/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-1-lfloor-sqrtn-rfloor?rq=1

Comment: Not really since here it converges.

Comment: Can you explain what Abel's rule you are referring to?

Comment: @Nûr: your last comment makes it even more obscure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

The sign is constant from $k^2$ to $(k+1)^2$, asymptotically corresponding to terms

$$\int_{k^2}^{(k+1)^2}\frac{dx}x=\log\left(1+ \frac1k\right)^2\approx \frac2k$$

and the alternating sum of $\dfrac1k$ is known to converge (to $\log2$).

Comment: That's a nice argument. Do you think it is easy to write a rigorous proof based on that observation ? (I don't ask for a proof).

Comment: @Nûr It should be easy to estimate the difference between the partial sum and the integral, and that should give a convergent sum.

Comment: @Nûr: instead of $x$ at the denominator, you can use $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and bracket between $1/(x+1)$ and $1/x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

## Hint:

We can find a pattern:
\begin{align}
&\bbox{\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{\left\lfloor{\root{n}}\right\rfloor} \over n}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\pars{{1 \over 1} + {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 3}} +
\pars{{1 \over 4} + {1 \over 5} + {1 \over 6} +{1 \over 7} + {1 \over 8}}
\\[2mm] &\
-\pars{{1 \over 9} + {1 \over 10} + {1 \over 11} + {1 \over 12} + {1 \over 13} +
 + {1 \over 14} + {1 \over 15}}
\\[2mm] &
+\pars{{1 \over 16} + {1 \over 17} + {1 \over 18} + {1 \over 19} + {1 \over 20} 
 + {1 \over 21} + {1 \over 22} + {1 \over 23} + {1 \over 24}}
\\[2mm] &
-\pars{{1 \over 25} + {1 \over 26} + {1 \over 27} + {1 \over 28} + {1 \over 29} 
 + {1 \over 30} + {1 \over 31} + {1 \over 32} + {1 \over 33} + {1 \over 34} + {1 \over 35}} + \cdots
\\[1cm] = &\
-H_{3} + \pars{H_{8} - H_{3}} - \pars{H_{15} - H_{8}} + \pars{H_{24} - H_{15}} -
\pars{H_{35} - H_{24}} + \cdots
\end{align}

> Note that each group in $\ds{\pars{}}$'s
>   $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{namely,}\ \pars{-1}^{n + 1}\pars{H_{n^{2} + 4n + 3} -
> H_{n^{2} + 2n}}\,,\ n = 1,2,3,\ldots}~}$ is $\ds{\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}}$ to
>   $\ds{\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,{2 \over n}}$ which agrees with
>   [$\texttt{@Ives Daoust}$ Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2787715/85343).

Comment: @i707107 Sorry but I don't see the $\textsf{typo}$.

Comment: Did you group the numbers differently than the numbers in the parentheses? If that is the reason for having $2$ in front, it would be better to explain it in one more line. Sorry about calling it a typo. Now, I can see your reasoning.

Comment: Even so, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} H_{n^2+2n} = \infty$. Then the series will be divergent.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but those series are not actually the same. $H_{n^2+2n}\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$, which implies divergence, but the series is known to converge. I think the rearrangement might not be valid because the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: @MichaelLee You are correct. The rearrangement is not valid here.

Comment: @MichaelLee Thanks for your advice. I already erase a little. It only leaves the hint.