# Convergence of $\sum\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I know this question has already been posted here ([Does $\sum\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor}}{ n}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787687/does-sum-frac-1-lfloor-sqrt-n-rfloor-n-converge?rq=1)) but I was wondering if there was a way to prove the series converges using the fact that for $n$ a natural number, $|\{ k\in  \mathbb{N}/\left\lfloor \sqrt{k} \right\rfloor=n\}|=2n+1$.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hmmm this makes me wonder whether $\sum_n (-1)^{f(n)}/n$ can diverge for some $f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ that has equal density of 0s and 1s as $n\to\infty$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it answers your question, but let for all $N$, $S_N = \sum_{k = 1}^N \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor}}{k}$. Then, as you notices, the sign of the terms changes after $1$, then $3$, then $5$, then etc. terms. In fact, we can write for all $N$,
$$
S_{N^2 - 1} = \sum_{k = 1}^{N^2 - 1} \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor}}{k} = \sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1} (-1)^n \sum_{k = n^2}^{(n + 1)^2 - 1} \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1} (-1)^n(H_{(n + 1)^2 - 1} - H_{n^2 - 1}).
$$
Now, let us write for all $n$, $H_n = \ln(n) + \gamma + \frac{C(n)}{n}$ with $(C(n))$ bounded (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). It implies that for all $n$,
\begin{align*}
(-1)^n(H_{(n + 1)^2 - 1} - H_{n^2 - 1}) & = (-1)^n\ln\left(\frac{(n + 1)^2 - 1}{n^2 - 1}\right) + (-1)^n\left(\frac{C((n + 1)^2 - 1)}{(n + 1)^2 - 1} - \frac{C(n^2 - 1)}{n^2 - 1}\right)\\
& = (-1)^n\ln\left(\frac{n(n + 2)}{(n - 1)(n + 1)}\right) + \mathrm{O}(n^{-2})\\
& = (-1)^n\ln\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n - 1}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right) + \mathrm{O}(n^{-2}).
\end{align*}
Any series of the knid $\sum \mathrm{O}(n^{-2})$ is absolutely convergent and $n \mapsto \ln\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n - 1}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$ decreases thus the series $\sum (-1)^n\ln\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n - 1}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$ converges. (Moreover, I believe it also absolutely converges, I let you finish the asymptotic developpement, you may end up with $\mathrm{O}(n^{-2})$ once more).

It proves that $S_{N^2 - 1}$ converges toward some limit $l \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $n$, let $N_n$ be the only integer such that $N_n^2 - 1 \leqslant n < (N_n + 1)^2 - 1$ and $s_n = (-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}$. We have,
\begin{align*}
S_n & = S_{N_n^2 - 1} + \sum_{k = N_n^2 - 1}^n \frac{s_n}{k}\\
& = l + s_n(H_n - H_{N_n^2 - 1}) + \mathrm{o}(1)\\
& = l + s_n(\ln(n) - \ln(N_n^2 - 1)) + \mathrm{o}(1).
\end{align*}
Using the fact that $1 \leqslant \frac{n}{N_n} \leqslant \frac{(N_n + 1)^2 - 1}{N_n^2 - 1} \rightarrow 1$, we deduce that $S_n = l + \mathrm{o}(1) \rightarrow l$.

Notice that the same proof would hold if you replaced $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ by $\lfloor n^\alpha \rfloor$ for any $0 < \alpha \leqslant 1$.

Comment: $\sum (-1)^n\ln\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n - 1}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$ is *not absolutely* convergent.

Comment: This should be edited as an answer to [the old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787687), instead of to this new one. It is not "using the fact that for n a natural number, $|\{ k\in  \mathbf{N}/\left\lfloor \sqrt{k} \right\rfloor=n\}|=2n+1$".